# Meteor global util helpers

Tags: meteor

Where do I define the functions that I want to use across the client code? Is it fine to define it with `Template.registerHelper()` although it is not necessarily intended to use inside templates? I want to be able to do something like `util.calculateDistance(a,b)` in any client code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the method globally or on a global object (don't use the var keyword to make it global):

```
util = {}  //instead of var util = {}

util.calculateDistance = function(a,b) {....}
```

Comment: I had to make sure that the file containing a global object should be in a deeper directory than other files that use it.